# How does the expect().to.be.true work in Chai?

Tags: javascript, chai

```
expect(true).to.be.true;
```

In this code, all the 'to', 'be', 'true' seems to be an attribute of the object response from 'expect(true)'.

How can these attributes work so that they can raise an exception?

Comment: I think it works via javascript's [`__defineGetter__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__) interface.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check the source code:

```
[ 'to', 'be', 'been'
  , 'is', 'and', 'has', 'have'
  , 'with', 'that', 'which', 'at'
  , 'of', 'same', 'but', 'does' ].forEach(function (chain) {
    Assertion.addProperty(chain);
});
```

and there is a `addProperty` in `utils`:
https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js

With this you can chain the properties infinitely like: `.to.be.to.to.to.be.equal()`

Let's create a simpler demonstration:

Assume that you have an `assert` object, with the `.true()` method

```
const assert = {
  'true': function (v) {
    return !!v
  }
}
```

and you want to be able to chain `.to` infinitely. Simply Use the `defineProperty` to define our getter:

```
Object.defineProperty(assert, 'to', {
  get() {
    return assert
  }
})
```

so now you can

```
assert.to.to.to.to.true(false)
```

working code: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/LLzBEX?editors=0012

---

I've added another more complex example here: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/dRVjXL?editors=0012

In this example you can see that there is some behaviors in the `.true` property.

We store the value from `expect()` in the internal `__expectObj` and the `__value` property, and then verify it in the getter of `.true`. So you can

```
expect(false).to.to.to.to.true
```

Comment: The code where `true` is a function is superfluous, I'm sure OP knows how to write a function.  The actual answer to the question is hidden behind a link; please move it to your answer.

Comment: Yeah, the case where `.true` is a property (not a method) is what I was most curious about, as well. In short, there's a getter function for `.true` that is triggered on a look-up as in `expect(false).true`, and that getter function runs the test... Wow, interesting!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at the source of [chai Assertion](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js) but the tl;dr is that Chai implements its own chainable methods on its assert library. However, special keywords are simply syntactic sugar as in the code below shows. Literally they are just properties that are added and can be chained but nothing truly is defined:

```
  /**
   * ### Language Chains
   *
   * The following are provided as chainable getters to improve the readability
   * of your assertions.
   *
   * **Chains**
   *
   * - to
   * - be
   * - been
   * - is
   * - that
   * - which
   * - and
   * - has
   * - have
   * - with
   * - at
   * - of
   * - same
   * - but
   * - does
   *
   * @name language chains
   * @namespace BDD
   * @api public
   */

  [ 'to', 'be', 'been'
  , 'is', 'and', 'has', 'have'
  , 'with', 'that', 'which', 'at'
  , 'of', 'same', 'but', 'does' ].forEach(function (chain) {
    Assertion.addProperty(chain);
  });
```

From there what it actually looks for are keywords it specifically defines. So one example is the keyword `.to.be.true` it will look at [`true` as defined](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js#L650) in the code snippet below

```
  /**
   * ### .true
   *
   * Asserts that the target is strictly (`===`) equal to `true`.
   *
   *     expect(true).to.be.true;
   *
   * Add `.not` earlier in the chain to negate `.true`. However, it's often best
   * to assert that the target is equal to its expected value, rather than not
   * equal to `true`.
   *
   *     expect(false).to.be.false; // Recommended
   *     expect(false).to.not.be.true; // Not recommended
   *
   *     expect(1).to.equal(1); // Recommended
   *     expect(1).to.not.be.true; // Not recommended
   *
   * A custom error message can be given as the second argument to `expect`.
   *
   *     expect(false, 'nooo why fail??').to.be.true;
   *
   * @name true
   * @namespace BDD
   * @api public
   */

  Assertion.addProperty('true', function () {
    this.assert(
        true === flag(this, 'object')
      , 'expected #{this} to be true'
      , 'expected #{this} to be false'
      , flag(this, 'negate') ? false : true
    );
  });
```