# JavaScript Set Prototype to Object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the following code to work.

```
Array.prototype.test = {
    func: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    }
};
```

Then when I run the following.

```
[].test.func();
```

The problem is the `this` within that function is the object `Array.prototype.test` **NOT** the array that I passed in.

I feel like there has to be way to do this without setting `Array.prototype.test` to a function and having to call it like so `[].test().func();`.

Chai uses this type of syntax quite a bit. So I'm assuming it's possible.

How can I get this to work as I'm expecting it to?

Comment: why not Array.prototype.test = function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this;
    }

Comment: @xianshenglu I mentioned this in my question. Because I have seen it done the other way, so I'm pretty sure it's possible. Chai is a great example of that. In my opinion the syntax of what I'm trying to achieve is a lot cleaner, and meets my needs better. It's also meant to be a learning experience, and not taking the cheap way out by trying to explore a new method of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaSript doesn't really have a good way to access that.

You could use a getter for `test` that returns a function with bound methods.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'test', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  get: function() {
    return {
      func: function() {
        console.log(this);
        return this;
      }.bind(this)
    };
  }
});

[].test.func();
```

But it's pretty convoluted compared to just using `.testFunc`.

```js
// Using Object.defineProperty to avoid enumerable prototype properties.
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'testFunc', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: function() {
    console.log(this);
    return this;
  }
});

[].testFunc();
```

See [How does the expect().to.be.true work in Chai?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756312/how-does-the-expect-to-be-true-work-in-chai) to see they do roughly the same thing.

Comment: Great detail and explanation. Really appreciate the through answer. And yes, I totally can see how it's more convoluted, but still great to understand the inner workings of JS a bit more and such. Thanks!