# In JavaScript, is it possible to have a class getter with the same name as a class function?

Tags: javascript

I understand that this may be an anti-pattern, but I'm curious how certain JavaScript libraries have the ability to chain JavaScript functions with optional parenthesis... (e.g. [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk))

An example of this would be...

```
let test = (new SomeClass()).initiate.parse(1).end;
let test = (new SomeClass()).initiate(1).parse.end;
```

Is there a way of doing this? I thought about maybe trying to do this with getters but the `get initiate()` of SomeClass was overridden by the class function `initiate()`.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  This is nightmare material.

Comment: @Brad Quite a few libraries have this type of pattern, for example, in chalk you can chain settings properties: `chalk.blue.underline.bold('with a blue substring')`. I'm curious how you create a pattern like this.

Comment: I've seen plenty with chaining by calling methods, like `chalk.blue().underline().bold()`, where each method effectively returns `this`, but I haven't seen any that abuse getters to cause an action to occur.

Comment: @Brad yeah, it seems like a very weird pattern but in the chalk documentation itself there's some form of that. That's what I was curious about. Same with a lot of testing libraries, they have code like: `expect.to.be.equal(4)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have a getter and a method with the same name.

You could achieve what you want though. One way is to use a Proxy in your getters to make it so that when a further property is accessed, that property of the original object is accessed instead.

```js
class SomeClass {

  get initiate ( ) {
    console.log( `Accessed initiate` );
    return new Proxy( x => {
      console.log( `Called initiate with arg ${x}` );
      this.stored = x;
      return this;
    }, { get: (_,prop) => this[prop] } );
  }
  
  get parse ( ) {
    console.log( `Accessed parse` );
    return new Proxy( x => {
      console.log( `Called parse with arg ${x}` );
      this.stored = x;
      return this;
    }, { get: (_,prop) => this[prop] } );
  }
  
  get end ( ) {
    return this.stored;
  }
  
}

console.log( (new SomeClass).initiate(2).parse.end );
console.log( (new SomeClass).initiate.parse(3).end );
console.log( (new SomeClass).initiate(5).parse(7).end );
```

Comment: Brilliant answer... just as a follow-up: if I wanted to get rid of `.end` but still allow both `.parse` and `.parse(3)` (e.g. have them both return the class instance) how would I create the conditional to return `this` instead of `this[prop]` in the proxy method `get` for `parse`. Or is that not possible?

Comment: @jscul I'm busy atm, but if you ping me in about 14-20 hours we can go over it in a chat. `.parse` and `.parse(3)` do both evaluate to the instance of SomeClass. You might not need end if all you want as the final result is that instance, or if you can use a valueOf instance method or better [`[Symbol.toPrimitive]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) to achieve your end goal.

Comment: @jscul Great :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

I would heavily recommend taking a look at how `chai` or other assertion libraries do this. For the code, you're looking for, you can look [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/core/assertions.js).

What they do is they define an `Assertion` class and define methods and properties separately. From there, [they use getters as you mentioned](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/utils/addProperty.js#L42) to achieve what you are trying to do with properties but they also keep methods separate (see [addMethod](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/master/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js))

Another question you can look at is [How does the expect().to.be.true work in Chai?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756312/how-does-the-expect-to-be-true-work-in-chai/44756499#44756499) where the accepted answer has a code example of how to get something very basic working.

I would be conscientious about having methods and properties the same name though. That can confuse a lot of people who are using your class as a consumer.